# submit button action not working in Struts2 framework

Tags: java, struts2

this is JSP page where action call get called

```jsp
<body>      
 hi welcome to
 <s:property value="username" />
 <s:submit action="allrecords" value="All Records Show"></s:submit>                
</body>
```

## List item

In struts xml:

```xml
<struts>

   <constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />

   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"             value="ApplicationResources"/> 

  <include file="loginfirst.xml"></include>

  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="reguser">
        <result>/login.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="loginprocess" class="com.org.struts.Loginprocess">

        <result name="success">/success.jsp
        </result>
        <result name="error">/login.jsp
        </result>
        <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>

    </action>

    <action name="allrecords" class="com.org.struts.FetchRecords">

        <result name="success">/allrecords.jsp
        </result>
    </action>



  </package>


  <package name="default" namespace="/legends" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="gettutorial" class="com.org.struts.Tutorial">

        <result name="success">/success.jsp
        </result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp
        </result>

    </action>

    <action name="addtutorial" class="com.org.struts.Tutorial"
        method="addmethod">

        <result name="success">/success.jsp
        </result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp
        </result>

    </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

## here's action class

```
public class FetchRecords extends ActionSupport   {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * 
     */
    ArrayList<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();  

    public ArrayList<User> getList() {  
        return list;  
    }  
    public void setList(ArrayList<User> list) {  
        this.list = list;  
    }  
    public String execute(){  
     try{  
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
              "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/strutssampleform", "root", "");  

      PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from USER_DETAIL");  
      ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  

      while(rs.next()){  
       User user=new User();  
       user.setFirstName(rs.getString(1));  
       user.setLastName(rs.getString(2));  
       user.setUsername(rs.getString(3));  
       user.setEmailid(rs.getString(5));  
       list.add(user);  
      }  

      con.close();  
     }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  

     return "success";  
    }

}
```

## List item

## allrecords display jsp

```jsp
<s:iterator  value="list">  
<fieldset>  
<s:property value="firstName"/><br/>  
<s:property value="lastName"/><br/>  
<s:property value="username"/><br/>  
<s:property value="emailid"/><br/>  
</fieldset>  
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: What you mean exactly by 'submit button action not working', Could you please mention in detail...!! ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the formatting is so bad that I can't even think to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You said that submit action is not working. I suppose that you have a `submit` tag that doesn't work. The problem that you use the action attribute with the submit tag. By default this feature is disabled. You may try to remove the action attribute and map a form to the action instead.

```jsp
<s:form action="allrecords">
 ...
 <s:submit value="All Records Show"/>
</s:form>
```